# Recommendations for algebra and trigonometry

Tags: online-resources

I always feel bad about my knowledge of algebra and trigonometry please tell me how to improve my algebra . Please recommend any video or book for self study elementary algebra and trigonometry

Comment: Practice. Practice. Practice.

Comment: along those lines:  Paul Halmos [wrote](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/4w96zy/the_right_way_to_learn_maths_paul_halmos/), "The only way to learn mathematics is to do mathematics"

Comment: Yes I am working on it but recommend me a good book for elementary algebra and trigonometry

Comment: consider Schaum's outlines